# Workflow initiation form new added checkbox disabled for current document libraries

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workflow, infopath, xsd.exe

In a sharepoint 2010 environment, there is a workflow assigned to some document libraries (actually Publishing Page libraries like Pages).

That workflow has a initiation form created in infopath.

I've added a new checkbox in to that form in infopath by doing below steps:

- Renamed the xsn document to cab and extracted the contents
- Opened the xsn document inside infopath designer and added the checkbox
- Since the control's values in form is accessed through the workflow using the Reach.cs class that is created using the xsd.exe; I created a new Reach.cs file using the xsd.exe for schema.xsd like "xsd.exe /c schema.xsd" and replaced the old one with this in the solution.
- Published the form to a network location
- Replaced the created xsn document with the one in the workflow solution
- Created a new package through the solution in the visual studio
- Retracted the solution in the server and removed it. Then deployed the new package

After these steps, I could see the initiation form (the wf is activated by publishing an item as a major version) with the new checkbox I added but it is disabled.

This is seen in the document libraries that is on the server before the deployment. But when I create a new document library and assign the same workflow to that document libary, the initiation form can be seen as expected with the newly added checkbox that is not disabled.

There is no error created in the log file.

The environment is a multi-server based and the option to remove the workflow from the current document libraries and assinging the same then is not a usable option for me since there are a lot of document libraries in the server and there is no easy saying this option to the guys at the operation side of the deployment.

It is an easy to reproduce case; so I'd be glad if you could try to create it in your envrionment or any advice could also do enough about me doing what wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is understood that, if there's ongoing workflows on the documents; the newly deployed workflow is not associated to these ones.

Since there can be workflows run for a month or longer; I guess this is a "by-design" issue.

So, after interrupting the workflows to the related documents, the newly deployed workflow can be seen in all of the document libraries.

Comment: it seems that, this is not the case. Waiting for another answer):